# How do I blit image along path in pygame?

Tags: pygame

Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve: http://bit.ly/cabifI
Basically I want the blue circle to move along the curve path back and forth when I press the right and left arrow keys.

I know I have to blit the image but is there a way to automatically determine the x,y coordinates of the path and blit the image into there while pressing the keys?

Or is there some king of algorithm/techniques that needs to be used?

Answer (score 1):

one way you can get the coordinates pretty easily is this:

```
y = int( math.cos(x/70) * 30 + surface.get_height()/2 )
```

assuming you use a resolution of 640x480, it will approximately describe your path

another way would be to make some pygame code to draw the path, and store it as a list we can call 'path' for instance. then you can get any x-coordinates' corresponding y coordinate by saying

```
path[x]
```

the code you want might look something like so:

```
path = list(0 for x in range(screen.get_width())) #make every y to 0 originally

while not <exit condition>:
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]: #if lmb is pressed
        mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x, y = mpos[0], mpos[1] #redundant, but for demonstrating
        path[x] = y #so this will map y coordinates to x coordinates

    draw_path(screen, path) #some function to draw you path, so its easier to make
```

of course theres some issues you must address, like if a coordinate has not been mapped it will be 0 and your ball wont move very smooth

you can generate the list 'path' using that 'cos'-function too, like such;

```
path = []
for x in range(len(screen.get_width())):
    y = int( math.cos(x/70) * 30 + surface.get_height()/2 )
    path.append(y)
```

also like mizipzor said you will have do adjust the ball so it looks like its rolling on top of the curve instead of through it

=)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bézier Curves, but it's overkill for what you're doing. Here's a nice tutorial intro on the topic: http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/ 
And Pygame example code: http://www.pygame.org/tags/bezier

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know the paths coordinates.

Given a single point along the path, place the ball on the same `x` but let `y = y - ballRadius - (lineWidth / 2)`.

A very simple approximation; you will probably have some intersections, especially on steep slopes, but it might do the trick.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know the coordinates of each point from the path. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: I see, well the obvious route now is to update your answer with how the path is generated. How do you draw a line which points you do not know? Are you using a library?

Comment: pygame is the only dependency but here's what I did: I edit the image and draw trace the path i want with a red line then in pygame I scanned the pixels from left to right then top to bottom. everytime I hit a red pixel, I record its coordinates.

Comment: Then you should know the points of the line (the points you recorded), try using those points in the formula I posted.